# Getting NSEntityDescription relationships

Tags: core-data, nsentitydescription

I have a core data model like so:

SALES_REP <--->> CUSTOMER <---->> PURCHASE_AGREEMENT <<------->> PRODUCTS

I can get the entity description for the Purchase Agreement and I can get the relationships (toCustomer and hasProducts)

```
[NSEntityDescription relationshipsByName];
```

but is it possible to get the Sales_Rep as well or do I have to pull that through the CUSTOMER entity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your diagram, `SALES_REP` isn't directly related to `PURCHASE_AGREEMENT`, it's only linked via `CUSTOMER`. That means `SALES_REP` doesn't know anything about `PURCHASE_AGREEMENT` on its own. So yes, you'll have to move on to the entity description for `CUSTOMER` and ask it for its `relationshipsByName`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but it would be easy to recursively look up relationships on an entity, then its related entities, and their related entities, etc, until you don't find any new ones.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I am duplicating the Purchase Agreement and need to get all the relationships up and down the chain.